# How wide should your arms be during face pulls?

Tags: execution

How wide should your arms be during face pulls? It's my newest addition to my arm days. I hope this exercise will improve my posture and smooth over muscle imbalances I may have. However, I'm not 100% sure how I should perform the exercise. In one video, an earlier one, Jeff Cavaliere is [happy](https://youtu.be/MiRAi2KOfRQ) with relatively narrow pulls. In another video, he specifically [advises](https://youtu.be/eIq5CB9JfKE) against that for the sake of external rotation and uses not one, but two ropes with his cable machine which allows him to keep his forearms perpendicular to the floor. I don't have a cable machine, but I do have a resistance band. It's hard for me to keep my hands that wide even with the lightest band. Should I bother or does it not matter that much?

Answer (score 1):

#### Hand width: wide enough to get good external rotation at the shoulder.

The point of this exercise is good external rotation at your shoulders. Jeff actually highlights this really well in the video you linked. Worrying about the minutia of your hand width probably isn't necessary here. As Jeff suggests, keeping finishing the movement with your forearms perpendicular to the floor is probably going to be the best place. In my personal experience doing facepulls, it is seems to be the most natural end point for the movement, and allows a good amount of external rotation, which is what you want. Keeping your hand closer to your head at the end range limits the amount of external rotation you can get, and having a large obtuse angle at the elbow turns the movement into more of a reverse fly than an external rotation movement.

#### Resistance band face pulls: the resistance curve is the opposite of the strength curve.

Jeff mentions this briefly in the linked video, but I'll give some further thoughts. Unfortunately, a resistance band is a really poor piece of equipment for doing face pulls. The resistance curve of the band and the strength curve of the movement are inverses. As the length of the band increases, the tension on the band increases. However, with a face pull, you are strongest at the beginning of the movement, and weakest at the end of the range of motion. This means that it's much too easy at the start, and gets much too hard at the end. It just isn't a great modality for the movement pattern, but if you can find a combination of band tension and starting position that seems to work through the full range of motion, then you're fine. I tried this morning with my bands and was just unable to find a position that really worked.

Answer (score -1):

This might be better explained with images or a video so here is a youtube video I found with good instructions for a face pull with a resistance band. However you do need some sort of column around your place to wrap the band around.

[image]
[image]
[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IndIttUTNMU

Comment: Welcome to the stack Jose, take the [tour] when you have a moment.

Comment: It is still important for your answer here to be able to stand without a link to the video, in the case that the link goes down or the video is removed. From the help center: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be helpful, but avoid making it necessary to click on them as much as possible."

Comment: That is what Jeff explicitly advised against